# Need suggestion on best structure to build a token dictionary in Python

Tags: python, data-structures, python-2.7

I am pretty new to python, and hope to get advice on this matter.

I wish to create a token dictionary in python. First and foremost, let me briefly describes what kind of feature I need.

1. Assuming each existing record should be {word, type, count}. E.g. snake, NN, 10
2. Whenever a new record {word, type} appears, it will check with the dictionary for existence. If found, count += 1. Else, add new record with count 1.
3. Dictionary is able to sort by highest count

Any suggestion on the best possible structure and show me example on it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `collections.Counter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)(introduced in py2.7):

```
In [52]: from collections import Counter

In [53]: c=Counter("aaabbc")

In [54]: c
Out[54]: Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1})

In [55]: c.most_common()
Out[55]: [('a', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 1)]
```

and in py2.6 you can use [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
In [58]: from collections import defaultdict

In [59]: strs="aaabbc"

In [61]: dic=defaultdict(int)

In [62]: for x in strs:
   ....:     dic[x]+=1
   ....:     

In [63]: dic
Out[63]: defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'a': 3, 'c': 1, 'b': 2})

In [64]: from operator import itemgetter

In [66]: sorted(dic.items(),reverse=True,key=itemgetter(1))
Out[66]: [('a', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 1)]
```

Answer (score 4):

[collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) has you covered.